# Pumping Lemma problem

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, regular-language

> Apply pumping lemma to each of these and prove that they are not regular.
>
> $L = \{ (0^p)(1^q)2 \mid 0 < q < p\}$
>
> $L_2 = \{ (a^p)(b^q)(c^r) \mid p = q \text{ or } q = r\}$

Here my bad attempt at $L$.

Proof: Assume $L$ is regular let $m$ be the number from the pumping lemma.

Let $w = 0^m 1^m 2$ this is clearly in $L$.

By the pumping theorem there exist words $w_1$, $w_2$, $w_3$ such that $w = w_1w_2w_3, |w_2|>0, |w_1w_2| \le m$.

This how far I got; it's not very far but the text is far from clear how to do this.

Comment: What does the pumping lemma have to say further?

Comment: You mean if I was to keep following my attempt?  To be honest the Linz book that I am using makes it into a sort of game.  Which makes it sort of hard to follow.

My finished attempt would include 
(for all symbol)i such that (Natural numbers) w1*w2*w3 exist in L.  So w2^l = a for some l exist in Natural numbers.  With this it is easy however to pick an i such that w1*w2^i *w3 = 0^m * 1^m * 2 does not exist in L

Comment: The "formal statement" on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) is what you're talking about when you mean the pumping lemma, right?

Comment: But if we let $w = 0^m1^{m-1}2$ with $m$ from the pumping lemma, then $w_1w_2$ as in pumping lemma consists of only zeroes. Hence $w_1w_3 = 0^k1^{m-1}2$ with $k < m$, hence not in $L$.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: Yet another proof of my own illiteracy.  ;-)

Comment: Your string doesn't belong to $L$...

Comment: Thanks for the help.  After, that I found an example of proof by the cases with the two I think I figured out how to do the second one.

Answer (score 2):

A fairly complete proof that the first language is not regular.

> If it were regular, then by the Pumping Lemma let $p$ be a pumping length for the language.  Consider the string $w = \mathtt{0}^p\mathtt{1}^{p-1}\mathtt{2} \in L$.  Since $|w| = p + (p-1)+ 1 = 2p \geq p$, by the Pumping Lemma $w$ may be written as $x y z$ where
>
> - $| x y | \leq p$;
> - $| y | > 0$; and
> - $x y^n z \in L$ for all $n \geq 0$.
>
> Since $| x y | \leq p$, and $xy$ is an initial segment of $w$, it follows that $xy$ must consist entirely of $\mathtt{0}$s, so in particular $x = \mathtt{0}^i$ and $y = \mathtt{0}^j$ for $i,j$ with $i + j \leq p$ and $j > 0$.  It also follows that $z = \mathtt{0}^{p-i-j} \mathtt{1}^{p-1} \mathtt{2}$.  Note that $x y^0 z \in L$, however $$x y^0 z = xz = \mathtt{0}^i \mathtt{0}^{p-i-j} \mathtt{1}^{p-1} \mathtt{2} = \mathtt{0}^{p-j} \mathtt{1}^{p-1} \mathtt{2},$$ and $p-j \leq p-1$, contradicting that $x y^n z$ belongs to $L$!

---

The second language can be shown to be non-regular by assuming $p > 1$ is a pumping length for it.  *(Note that if $p$ is a pumping length for a language $L$ then every $p^\prime > p$ is also a pumping length for $L$, so the assumption $p > 1$ won't affect whether the language satisfies the conclusion of the Pumping Lemma.)*  Now look at the string $w = \mathtt{a}^p \mathtt{b}^p \mathtt{c}$.

Comment: Replacing $p$ by $p+1$ in both arguments will avoid the $p > 1$ condition.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: I thought of that, but decided on this formulation.  I'm still not certain which is better, though I think I will at least add a small note.